# Closest Table of The Closest Table

Tags: javascript, jquery, parent, closest

My Question is how can I select the `.closest('table')` of the `.closest('table')`.

I tried:

```
$('div').closest('table').closest('table').hide();
```

and it didn't work, is there a way to select the closest table of the closest table?

Comment: give it an id or a class and you are set. oh and it is also faster

Comment: You have a typo - there should be a . between your div selector and the first closest call.

Comment: Did you check the console at all? Didn't work should be accompanied by what happened instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dot missing before first closest

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/r7Kh9/1/)**

```
$('div').closest('table').closest('table').hide();
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use .parents for this:

```
$('div').parents('table').eq(1).hide();
```

0 would be closest, 1 second closest, 2 third closest, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can put an ID at the first table:

```
<table id="firstTable">
$('div').closest('#firstTable').hide();
```